# How do I iterate over a list of value pairs to set the respective value equal to a list of new values?

Tags: python, list, loops, tuples

I think my question is mostly likely best explained by the following example:

```
new_values = [3, 2, 1]

pairs = [(value,whatever), (value2,whatever2), (value3,whatever3)]
```

I want to set each value within pairs equal to its respective new value in new_values. In other words, I'd like

```
pairs = [(3,whatever), (2,whatever2), (1,whatever3)]
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried already? Can you show your code and indicate what difficulties you are having?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip`, which is meant to loop through two lists in parallel:

```
[(x, z) for x, (y, z) in zip(new_values, pairs)]
# [(3, 'whatever'), (2, 'whatever2'), (1, 'whatever3')]
```

Comment: bah! beat me to it! :P :) Mine actually didn't bother doing the (y, z) and I did the direct [1] access in the tuple creation. I like the unpacking of yours nicer!

Comment: Nice! You can replace y by an underscore ;)